# How can I integrate BingMaps into WPF Window?

Tags: c#, wpf, maps, setparent

I want to integrate the BingMaps App from Win10 into my CarPC solution.

I tried different things without getting it to work. My first approach was to use start the Process and set it into my Application like that:

```
p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApp\\Microsoft.WindowsMaps_5.1606.1670.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\\Maps.exe");
host.Process = p;
```

This works fine for Notepad an other stuff, but can't start the `Maps.exe`.

So I tried using:

```
p = Process.GetProcessById(11320);
```

The number is the `ProcessID` from WinSpy, again it is working with several other applications.

I'am not sure what I did wrong i tried almost 5 days now with several different approaches.

I am using Win10 x64 maybe that is the Problem, all the other solutions I've found are using `user32.dll`.

EDIT:
The goal ist to set the parent of the Maps Application included in Windows 10. To my Form, so I have only one Window in Full Screen including Navigation via BingMaps and have the control over my Music while driving.
I don't want to reprogramm a Map application.

Answer (score -1):

First you have to Create a Bing Maps Developer Account, after Download the Bing Maps Windows Presentation Foundation Control:

https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=1f735eac-d893-4814-84e8-20f00fa617ba

And after you create the code:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh830433.aspx